# Why 1st imageview's pic vanishes if i take pic for 2nd imageview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

Screen contains two images. **here for `profilePicImage` if i choose from library and for `rightProfilePicImg` if i take pic with camera then `profilePicImage` pic vanishes why?** how ever if i use library for two imageviews then it works fine

i am picking images for two imageviews like below: here `profilePicImage` and `rightProfilePicImg` are twoimageviews

```
extension ProfileViewController : EasyImagePickerDelegate{

func didSelect(image: UIImage?, video: URL?, fileName: String?) {
    
    if let img = image {
        if chooser == .profile {
            profilePicImage.image = img
        }
        else if chooser == .right {
            rightProfilePicImg.image = img
        }
    }
}
}
```

**code for EasyImagePickerDelegate:**

```
public protocol EasyImagePickerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didSelect(image: UIImage?, video : URL?, fileName : String?)
}

open class EasyImagePicker: NSObject {

private let pickerController: UIImagePickerController
private weak var presentationController: UIViewController?
private weak var delegate: EasyImagePickerDelegate?

public enum mediaType {
    case images
    case video
}

public init(presentationController: UIViewController, delegate: EasyImagePickerDelegate) {
    self.pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    super.init()
    self.presentationController = presentationController
    self.delegate = delegate
    self.pickerController.delegate = self
    self.pickerController.allowsEditing = true
}

public func present(from sourceView: UIView, mediaType : mediaType, onViewController : UIViewController) {
    sourceView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    if mediaType == .images{
        self.pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
        let actionCamera = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .default) { (action) in
            if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) == .notDetermined{
                let _ = self.checkCameraPermission()
                self.presentAlert(sourceView: sourceView, alertController: alertController)
            }else{
                if self.checkCameraPermission(){
                    self.pickerController.sourceType = .camera
                    self.presentationController?.present(self.pickerController, animated: true)
                }else{
                    self.presentCameraSettings(with: "We need camera access for capturing picture.", fromView: onViewController)
                }
            }
        }
        
        if let actionLibrary  = self.checkPhotoLibrary(isVideo: false, sourceView: sourceView, onViewController: onViewController, alertController: alertController){
            alertController.addAction(actionLibrary)
        }
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){ alertController.addAction(actionCamera) }
    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    cancel.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    alertController.addAction(cancel)
    presentAlert(sourceView: sourceView, alertController: alertController)
}

private func checkPhotoLibrary(isVideo : Bool,sourceView : UIView,onViewController : UIViewController,alertController : UIAlertController)-> UIAlertAction?{
    let actionLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "\(isVideo ? "Video" : "Photo") Library", style: .default) { (action) in
        if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined{
            let _ = self.checkPhotoLibraryPermission()
            self.presentAlert(sourceView: sourceView, alertController: alertController)
        }else{
            if self.checkPhotoLibraryPermission(){
                self.pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                self.presentationController?.present(self.pickerController, animated: true)
            }else{
                self.presentCameraSettings(with: "We gallery permission for pick \(isVideo ? "video" : "photo") from you.", fromView: onViewController)
            }
        }
    }
    return actionLibrary
}

private func pickerController(_ controller: UIImagePickerController, image: UIImage?, video : URL?, file : String?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.delegate?.didSelect(image: image, video: video, fileName: file)
}
}

extension EasyImagePicker: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    if let mediaURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL  {
        self.pickerController(picker, image: nil, video: mediaURL, file: mediaURL.lastPathComponent)
    }else{
        self.pickerController(picker, image: nil, video: nil, file: nil)
    }
    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
        return self.pickerController(picker, image: nil, video: nil, file: nil)
    }
    self.pickerController(picker, image: image, video: nil, file: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo code is causing the trouble here

Comment: if you could provide a github demo of the problem we can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension EasyImagePicker: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        if let mediaURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL  {
            self.pickerController(picker, image: nil, video: mediaURL, file: mediaURL.lastPathComponent)
        }else{
            guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
            return self.pickerController(picker, image: nil, video: nil, file: nil)
        }
        self.pickerController(picker, image: image, video: nil, file: nil)
    }
        }
       
    }
```